# Utility for FIX to verify message

Tags: fix-protocol

Anyone aware of a FIX utility available online to verify fix messages? ie: accept a fix message and check things like body length length and checksum.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fix log decoder on https://fixspec.com. When you enter a message it is parsed and items such as checksum and body length are also checked. You need to register to access it, but registration is free.

Answer (score 4):

https://drewnoakes.com/fix-decoder/ is a nice **online** FIX decoder that supports *Checksum(9)* and *BodyLength(8)* tags validation.

No registration required.

Comment: this is great in validating checksum and bodylength. But,sometimes fails when garbled data is present. make sure data is not garbled. and, this will not check required tags.

Answer (score 0):

One that I know of is [ValidFix](http://www.validfix.com/fix-analyzer.html). There was a link to it on the QuickFix website, but it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a licensed tool called VeriFIX http://www.greenlinetech.com/products/verifix.php.
Pasting it incase if it's useful to you or others.